# Haskell couldn't match type Data.Time.Clock.UTC.NominalDiffTime with Int

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get UTC timestamp in haskell. The original function `getPOSIXTime` gives timestamp in seconds. I want it in milli and microseconds. I wrote a function to multiply seconds timestamp by a factor like this:

```
-- get timestamp in seconds multiplied by factor
getTimestampX :: Int -> IO Int
getTimestampX n = do
    tstamp <- fmap (truncate . (* n)) getPOSIXTime
    let str = show tstamp
        intval = read str :: Int
    return intval
```

However this is throwing the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘time-1.6.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.NominalDiffTime’
                     with ‘Int’
      Expected type: IO Int
        Actual type: IO POSIXTime
    • In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘getPOSIXTime’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        tstamp <- fmap (truncate . (* n)) getPOSIXTime
      In the expression:
        do { tstamp <- fmap (truncate . (* n)) getPOSIXTime;
             let str = show tstamp
                 intval = ...;
             return intval }
```

But if I use any integer value like 100, 1000 in place of `n` then it is working fine. Am I missing some concept here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `truncate ` can already return an `Int`. You don't need to `show` and then `read` it. So: `getTimestampX n = truncate . (* fromIntegral n) <$> getPOSIXTime`. (Not making this an answer because it doesn't explain the problem, only solves it; there's already a good answer with explanations.)

Comment: I liked this answer more.  Had it been in the answer section, I would have marked it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `getPOSIXTime` returns `IO POSIXTime`, not `IO Int`

That works:

```
getTimestampX :: POSIXTime -> IO Int
getTimestampX n = do
    tstamp <- fmap (truncate . (* n)) getPOSIXTime
    let str = show tstamp
        intval = read str :: Int
    return intval
```

Your case with a raw number worked, because `Haskell` can infer `10` to `POSIXTime`. But when you provide a variable with a defined type `Int`, compiler fails to match types.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and an explanation.

Comment: However, if you look at the comment in the question above, it also has a solution which works even without using POSIXTime instead of Int. Nice explanation though.